# How to Update an Entity in a Google app engine data store partially

Tags: java, google-app-engine, resteasy, objectify

I am using Objectify in Google App Engine for Data Store. I am having an Entity with 6 Properties.
For Example,

- Key (id)
- FirstName
- LastName
- Age
- mobile_Number
- Email

  I need to write an Update Endpoint for the Entity. I want that update Endpoint should be able to update the Entity with the specified fields Not the Entire Entity. For Example If I want to update the **mobile_number**, it should update the mobile number alone. or If i want to update the **firstName** it should update that only.

For that I need to write a common method to update the Entity based on the fields.

Many thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i fixed this update in the following way.

Got the input parameter as Hashmap where i can get the user's properties that to be updated. The hashmap's key should be same as Entity's property value.

```
public Response update(HashMap<String, String> ProfileEntity) {
 //update logic
}
```

and updated the value based on the following if condition:

```
        ProfileEntity existingEntity = getById(ProfileEntity.get("key"));

        if(existingEntity == null)
            System.out.println("Invalid Profile Key");

        if(ProfileEntity.containsKey("firstName"))
            existingEntity.setFirstName(ProfileEntity.get("firstName"));

        if(ProfileEntity.containsKey("lastName"))
            existingEntity.setLastName(ProfileEntity.get("lastName"));

        if(ProfileEntity.containsKey("age"))
            existingEntity.setAge(ProfileEntity.get("age")));

        if(ProfileEntity.containsKey("mobile_Number"))
            existingEntity.setMobileNumber(ProfileEntity.get("mobile_Number"));

        super.save(existingEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You load and save the entity in a transaction.

```
ofy().transact(() -> {
    Thing thing = ofy().load().key(key).now();
    thing.setWhatever();
    ofy().save().entity(thing);
});
```

Transactions guarantee that all units of work are effectively executed in serial. Not *actually* executed in serial, but the data will be consistent as if all units of work were serialized.

Comment: For the thing.setWhatever() i should know that which field to update,  then only i can set the setfirstName() or setMobileNumber() right.

Answer (score 0):

I used spring BeanUtils for this.

```
 public static String[] getNullPropertyNames(Object source) {
        final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
        java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

        Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<String>();
        for (java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
            Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
            if (srcValue == null) emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
        }
        String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];
        return emptyNames.toArray(result);
    }

    public static void copyProperties(Object src, Object target) {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, target, getNullPropertyNames(src));
    }
```

Then use your update like this

```
 public Publisher update(@Named("id") Long id, Publisher publisher) throws Exception {
        checkExists(id);
        Publisher destination = get(id);
        copyProperties(publisher, destination);
        return insert(destination);
    }
```

**NOTE:** This method will not overide null and list properties.